# no of intersection points.!

Tags: combinatorics

Prove that if each of $m$ points in one straight line be joined to each of $n$ in a parallel straight line by straight line segments terminating at the points, then excluding the given points, the line segments will intersect $\frac14mn(m-1)(n-1)$ times. **Note:** The count is of intersections, **not** of points of intersection. E.g., in the picture below for the case $m=n=3$, each red dot represents one intersection, but the large black dot in the centre represents *three* intersections, one for each pair of segments intersecting at that point. (I did not bother to include the original straight lines on which the points lie; they’re pretty obvious and just clutter up the picture.)

[image]

Comment: i have given the wording exactly as given in the question

Comment: Okay, but I think it is hard to understand, can you write the question in your own words?

Comment: Are the two straight lines parallel, or do you consider the cases when the straight lines intersect?

Comment: A suggestion for rewording: paragraph 1, "Let two (parallel?) lines $p$ and $q$ be given. On line $p$ (describe points) are given, and on line $q$ (describe points) are given. Between these points (describe what)." Paragraph 2, "Prove that (use terms from paragraph 2) have (TeX-written formula; mathematics lovers should make an effort to learn at least basics of TeX)."

Answer (score 1):

There's a problem if we allow the lines to intersect, for example:

[image: Problem with intersecting lines]

results in no intersections.

If the two lines are parallel, we have a unique intersection for any pair of $2$-element subsets: one from each line.  This is illustrated below:

[image: Parallel lines illustration]

Conversely, any such intersection occurs between such pairs.  The number of such pairs is $$\binom{m}{2}\binom{n}{2},$$ as required.

Comment: How does this take care of the problem that you might have two pairs of four that intersect at the same place?